# Node serveless Cors on Vercel

Tags: node.js, typescript, cors, serverless, vercel

Im having some issues with enabling cors for a node function running on vercel.

I have the following in a file `api/index.ts`

```
import type {VercelRequest, VercelResponse} from '@vercel/node';

export default (req: VercelRequest, res: VercelResponse) => {
  return res.status(200).json({hello: 'world'});
};
```

and this is the `vercel.json` in the root of the project.

```
{
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/api/(.*)",
        "headers": [
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
          { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

When deployed to vercel and fetching from a localhost

```
fetch('https://myapp.vercel.app/api').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = `data`;
});
```

I get the cors error stating that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myapp.vercel.app/api. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
```

Is there addition setup needed for the headers to be sent?

I have tried various suggestions found from googling, most of the cors issues raised are for Next ( which I am not using ) the only dep is on the `Vercel/node` package ( for types ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified a CORS policy for endpoints that match pattern `/api/(.*)`,

```
"source": "/api/(.*)",
```

but you're requesting `/api`, which does *not* match that pattern. Either requesting `/api/` instead of `/api` or modifying your pattern accordingly should solve the issue.

Besides, be aware that [the wildcard (`*`) isn't compatible with credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards). Because you don't seem to need requests with credentials, you should be able to safely drop the following line from your CORS config anyway:

```
{ "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
```